# template field (button) of the grid executing on page refresh

Tags: asp.net

I have a button as template field in my hierarchical grid and on that button I am updating some data but when user hit the browser refresh button it executes by itself ..whats the solution..

here is my code behind

```
        protected void GridView1_RowCommand(Object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
          {
              if (!Page.IsPostBack)
              {
                  if (e.CommandName == "UpdateBillData")
                  {

                      GridViewRow row = ((Control)e.CommandSource).NamingContainer as GridViewRow;
                      int index = row.RowIndex;

                      int billgenID = Convert.ToInt32(GridView1.DataKeys[index].Value);

                      DropDownList ddmonths = (DropDownList)row.FindControl("DDBillingMonths");
                      TextBox cunit = (TextBox)row.FindControl("txtCurrBillUnits");
                      TextBox amountbDue = (TextBox)row.FindControl("txtAmountBDueDate");
                      TextBox advItax = (TextBox)row.FindControl("txtAdvIncomeTax");
                      TextBox whtax = (TextBox)row.FindControl("txtWholdingTax");
                      TextBox gst = (TextBox)row.FindControl("txtGst");
                      TextBox amountafterdd = (TextBox)row.FindControl("txtAmtAfterDD");
                      TextBox duedate = (TextBox)row.FindControl("txt_BillDueDate");
                      TextBox billingdate = (TextBox)row.FindControl("txt_BillGenDate");
                      TextBox remarks = (TextBox)row.FindControl("txtOthers");

                      //Update Bill Data Procedure
                      Database db = DatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase();

                      DbCommand cmd = db.GetStoredProcCommand("sp_Update_GenBill");

                      db.AddInParameter(cmd, "@gridrowID", System.Data.DbType.Int32);
                      db.SetParameterValue(cmd, "@gridrowID", billgenID);

                      db.AddInParameter(cmd, "@bmonth", System.Data.DbType.String, 3);
                      db.SetParameterValue(cmd, "@bmonth", ddmonths.SelectedValue);

                      //Execute Stored Procedure
                      int i = 0;
                      i = db.ExecuteNonQuery(cmd);

                      if (i != 0)
                      {
                          showalert("Succesfuly Updated...");
                      }
                      else
                          showalert("Error occured while updating...");
                  }
              }
         }
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess is your last postback before each refresh was a control with a command associated with it. When you hit REFRESH in your browser, it actually reposts the command. Try just going to your browser's address field and hitting ENTER. Do you get the same results?

Comment: i have a GridView and this button is a control associated with it. Whats the solution

Comment: Surprisingly the problem seems to be resolved by putting the UPDATE PANEL around the button..hummm strange.

Comment: UpdatePanel only refreshes what's in the panel instead of the entire page. So if your command was really firing, it's still firing...

Comment: I've checked thoroughly and tried giving inputs and then refresh and surprisingly no change in database but in the previous scenario it was updating the database on page refresh..indeed strange.